# Apply to job with resume created from profile resulted in error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, 500-server-error

A few moments ago, I attempted to apply to a job listing.  I wrote my cover letter, and used my profile as my resume.  I did not remove or otherwise bother with the sections.

After clicking send or submit, I was greeted with Statler and Waldorf.  Was any portion of my application sent?

Edit:
And should I attempt sending it again.  I ask because if the first was sent, and I send another, it will look kind of odd.  "This guy apparently doesn't internet well.  He sent in two applications for the same job."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've just checked your account and no job applications have been recorded or sent.

Can you please try applying again and let me know if you were successful?

Comment: It appears to have worked.  The form that was displayed when sending the Cover letter and resume was slightly different this time.  The previous time the resume created from my profile was not depicted on the submission form, whereas this time {MYNAME}.pdf was on there as a selectable resume to attach.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Cool, we can see it now - Welcome! :)